# Matlab: element wise complex conjugate transpose?

Tags: matlab

`vi` is a 10 by 1 complex vector.

`c = [v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6]` is a list of 10 by 6 containing them.

What is the fastest or general way to produce `d = [v1' v2' v3' v4' v5' v6']` where complex conjugate transpose is applied to each vector, and `d` being 1 by 60?

Comment: Doesn't `c'` work for you?

Comment: May be, `c(:)'` is what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphically speaking, if this is what you want (`|` is a number and `+` is its conjugate):

```
     |           |  |  |  |  |  |
     |           |  |  |  |  |  |
vi = |   ,  c =  |  |  |  |  |  |  , d = +++++ +++++ +++++ +++++ +++++ +++++
     |           |  |  |  |  |  |
     |           |  |  |  |  |  |
```

You would need to do:

```
d = c(:)';
```

**Explanation**: `c(:)` reshapes (reorganizes) the array such that every column appears below the preceding one (thus making one long column vector); then `'` performs the conjugate transpose turning it into a row vector, as needed.